# If I use a Dorje with a power that's on my class list, but that was crafted by a class that has it at a lower level, must I make a UPD check?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, psionics

I was recently buying magical items for my Kobold Wilder and I wanted to get a Dorje of Body Adjustment to have backup healing. I looked at the price of a level 3 dorje(11,250gp) and it was a bit out of my price range. So I looked to see if there were any classes who learned it earlier.

I found that Psychic warriors have it as a second-level Power which puts its Dorje cost much lower and within my price range as a second level power (2nd level Dorje cost 4500gp).

What I want to know is: Do I need to make a Use Psi Device check because the power is *technically* on my Class list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you would not need an UPD check. Dorjes use the [power trigger activation method](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/items/basics.htm#powerTrigger), which states:

> If a power is on a character’s power list, the character knows how to use a power trigger item that stores that power.

With no caveats about power levels or class restrictions.